# Jquery UI Sortable Twin list

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have two same list and when I change the order of one list I want the other to be reorder too.

It's for a admin way, I choose to edit the order and I have a inline popup with the admin content. (So only one list has the sortable active, the other list must only reflect the change.)

Thanks.

Jsffidle here to start : http://jsfiddle.net/jZRKD/

Answer (score 0):

Simple example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jZRKD/2/)

For more complex situation, you should look at jQuery.fn.sort() and .detach() to keep events on objects.